# Retrieve data from sql table and display in view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok guys so im new to MVC i have already constructed models and controllers to insert data  into sql table but now i want to retrieve this data to another View. My code so far:

so i have a sql table called "ProductTable" with 4 entities "ID" "Name" "Broi" and "Cena"

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductTable] (
    [ID]   INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [Broi] INT        NOT NULL,
    [Cena] NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

and i have already saved some data in this table

i   have a model class

```
[Table("ProductTable")]
public class ProductTable
{
    //public int ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Broi { get; set; }

    public int Cena { get; set; }
}
```

and another model class for  DbContext

```
public class DefaultConnection : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ProductTable> Products { get; set; }
}
```

controller to retrive data from View and Pass it to model

```
public ActionResult Table()
{
    return View(new ProductTable());
}

[HttpPost]       
public ActionResult Table(ProductTable product)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(product);
    }
    using (var contex = new DefaultConnection())
    {
        contex.Products.Add(product);
        contex.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View();
}
```

and a View to this controller with TextBoxes and submit button
But now i want to retrive the saved data and display it to anoter View.
I have tried  this but i got an error:

> The 'Cena' property on 'ProductTable' could not be set to a 'String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'

```
private DefaultConnection db = new DefaultConnection();

public ViewResult TableData()
{
    return View(db.Products.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the database table the column `cena` is of type `NChar` and in the `model` it is of `type int`

### How is this supposed to work

```
//Change this
public int Cena { get; set; }

//to this
public String Cena { get; set; }
```